# Use tailwind @apply in CSS modules in Next.js

Tags: next.js, css-modules, tailwind-css

I've setup tailwind with my Next.js site as per the official guide here: https://github.com/tailwindcss/setup-examples/tree/master/examples/nextjs

However, when I try and use the `@apply` method, in a [CSS module on a component level](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css), eg:

```
.container {
  @apply rows-span-3;
}
```

I get the following error:

Syntax error: `@apply` cannot be used with `.rows-span-3` because `.rows-span-3` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.rows-span-3` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

This is my `postcss.config.js`:

```
const purgecss = [
  '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
  {
    content: ['./components/**/*.jsx', './pages/**/*.jsx'],
    defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
  },
]

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
    'postcss-import',
    'postcss-mixins',
    'postcss-calc',
    'postcss-extend',
    ['postcss-color-mod-function', {
      importFrom: [
        './assets/styles/vars.css',
      ],
    }],
    ['postcss-preset-env', {
      stage: 1,
      preserve: false,
      importFrom: [
        './assets/styles/vars.css',
      ],
    }],
    'tailwindcss',
    'autoprefixer',
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [purgecss] : []),
    'postcss-nested',
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I manage to make it work using this example
[link to tailwind doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)

From the doc:

You have this module css

```
/*Button.module.css*/
.error {
  @apply bg-red-800 text-white;
}
```

Component file

```
//Button.js
import styles from './Button.module.css'

export function Button() {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      // Note how the "error" class is accessed as a property on the imported
      // `styles` object.
      className={styles.error}
    >
      Destroy
    </button>
  )
}
```

***From the example, please notice the use of  `className={styles.error}` instead of  `className="error"`***